# Unit testing method which is using a private field initialized with static method

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, mockito

In my class `TwitchService` I'm creating a private field `twitchClient` using `TwitchClientBuilder`. How can I approach testing method `sendChatMessage()` which is using `twitchClient`?

```
public class TwitchService {

    public TwitchService(){
        twitchClient = TwitchClientBuilder.builder().build();
    }

    public void sendChatMessage(String content) throws Exception {
        if(content.isEmpty()){
            throw new Exception("Cannot send empty message!");
        }

        twitchClient.getChat().sendMessage(content);
    }
}
```

So far, I have tried mocking `TwitchClientBuilder.builder()` and `twitchCliendBuilder.build()` like this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TwitchServiceTest {

    private TwitchService twitchService;

    @Mock
    private TwitchClientBuilder twitchClientBuilder;


    @Test
    public void sendChatMessage() throws Exception {

        try (MockedStatic<TwitchClientBuilder> twitchClientBuilderMockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(TwitchClientBuilder.class)){
            twitchClientBuilderMockedStatic.when(() -> TwitchClientBuilder.builder()).thenReturn(mock(TwitchClientBuilder.class));

            when(twitchClientBuilder.build()).thenReturn(mock(TwitchClient.class));
            twitchService = new TwitchService("x", "y");
            twitchService.sendChatMessage("test message");
        }

    }
}
```

But I get `NullPointerException` on `twitchClient` in `sendChatMessage()`
Any ideas how to properly mock fields like this?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to test ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *constructor dependency injection* for `TwitchClient`, instead of hard-coding it by calling builder.

Simply re-write your service, like so:

```
public class TwitchService {

    private final TwitchClient twitchClient

    public TwitchService(final TwitchClient twitchClient) {
        this.twitchClient = twitchClient;
    }

...
}
```

`TwitchService` is now loosely-coupled with the implementation of `TwitchClient`, which gives you ability to mock the client in the unit tests and use real-implementation (unit tested by itself) in real-code.

So in unit-test, we can mock `TwitchClient`:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TwitchServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private TwitchClient mockedTwitchClient;

    // Tested instance
    private TwitchService twitchService;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        twitchService = new TwitchService(mockedTwitchClient);
    }

    @Test
    public void ourTest() {
        when(mockedTwitchClient.xyz()).thenReturn(...);
        ...
    }
```

and in the real code, we "inject" real `TwitchClient` built by `TwitchClientBuilder`:

```
...
twitchService = new TwitchService(TwitchClientBuilder.builder().build());
...
```